# Break a string of CSVs from LISTAGG (Oracle) into columns that line up correctly

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, listagg

This is my first time posting a question on stackoverflow, so I apologize in advance for whatever I'm doing wrong. :)

In Oracle SQL Developer ver 17.2 (on Oracle 12.1), I am writing a complex query which joins employee information from various tables. One of the tables that I am joining (EMPEXAMS) contains employee exams, scores, and dates. Employees may take any of 15 different exams, and each exam can be taken multiple times. The EMPEXAMS table simply contains a row for each exam score/date, but my query generates one row for each employee, and I need to have score and date columns for all 15 exam codes in my results. So my output table would be:

```
EMP_ID | EXAM1_SCORE | EXAM1_DATE | EXAM2_SCORE |  EXAM2_DATE        | ...to EXAM15  
-------|-------------|------------|-------------|--------------------------------
10001  |          95 | 08-APR-2017|      98, 86 |  11-DEC-2017, 12-JAN-2016
```

I need two columns (Exam Score and Exam Date) for each of the 15 exam types even though most will be empty because employees do not take all of them. Also, when employees take the same exam more than once, I list them as comma separated values in the column for that exam code.

To get all of the exam data on one row, I am using LISTAGG to create a string of exams for each employee which look like this example (for Employee 10001):

```
EXAM1, 95, 08-APR-2017, EXAM2, 98, 11-DEC-2017, EXAM2, 86, 12-JAN-2016, 
EXAM5, 88, 14-FEB-2018, EXAM7, 99, 20-OCT-2017, EXAM7, 94, 20-DEC-2016, 
EXAM9, 97, 24-NOV-2015, EXAM10, 93, 24-JUL-2016
```

Here is the code showing the join:

```
--Certifications - Join to main Employee table 'a' 
left join (  

select distinct 
EMP_ID,  
LISTAGG(EXAM_CODE || ', ' || EXAM_SCORE || ', ' || EXAM_DATE, ', ')  
 within group (order by EXAM_CODE, EXAM_SCORE DESC, EXAM_TEST_DATE)  
 "EXAM SCORES AND DATES"

from "EMPEXAMS"

group by EMP_ID
order by EMP_ID
) Exam_Scores
on a.EMP_ID = Exam_Scores.EMP_ID
```

Up in the main select statement, I break it up into columns like this:

```
-- Exam Scores broken into columns  
SELECT  
a.EMP_ID,  
regexp_substr(Exam_Scores."EXAM SCORES AND DATES", '[^,]+', 1, 2) "EXAM1_SCORE",  
regexp_substr(Exam_Scores."EXAM SCORES AND DATES", '[^,]+', 1, 3) "EXAM1_DATE",  
regexp_substr(Exam_Scores."EXAM SCORES AND DATES", '[^,]+', 1, 5) "EXAM2_SCORE",  
regexp_substr(Exam_Scores."EXAM SCORES AND DATES", '[^,]+', 1, 6) "EXAM2_DATE",  
regexp_substr(Exam_Scores."EXAM SCORES AND DATES", '[^,]+', 1, 8) "EXAM3_SCORE",  
regexp_substr(Exam_Scores."EXAM SCORES AND DATES", '[^,]+', 1, 9) "EXAM3_DATE",  
regexp_substr(Exam_Scores."EXAM SCORES AND DATES", '[^,]+', 1, 11) "EXAM4_SCORE",  
regexp_substr(Exam_Scores."EXAM SCORES AND DATES", '[^,]+', 1, 12) "EXAM4_DATE",  
regexp_substr(Exam_Scores."EXAM SCORES AND DATES", '[^,]+', 1, 14) "EXAM5_SCORE",  
regexp_substr(Exam_Scores."EXAM SCORES AND DATES", '[^,]+', 1, 15) "EXAM5_DATE",  
regexp_substr(Exam_Scores."EXAM SCORES AND DATES", '[^,]+', 1, 17) "EXAM6_SCORE",  
regexp_substr(Exam_Scores."EXAM SCORES AND DATES", '[^,]+', 1, 18) "EXAM6_DATE",  
regexp_substr(Exam_Scores."EXAM SCORES AND DATES", '[^,]+', 1, 20) "EXAM7_SCORE",  
regexp_substr(Exam_Scores."EXAM SCORES AND DATES", '[^,]+', 1, 21) "EXAM7_DATE",  
regexp_substr(Exam_Scores."EXAM SCORES AND DATES", '[^,]+', 1, 23) "EXAM8_SCORE",  
regexp_substr(Exam_Scores."EXAM SCORES AND DATES", '[^,]+', 1, 24) "EXAM8_DATE",  
... and so on through EXAM15
```

The problem with my attempted solution is that the columns are simply being filled in from left to right, with no mechanism to put the exams in the correct columns (according to the exam code). For example, Employee 10001 took EXAM2 twice, so both EXAM2 scores/dates should appear in the EXAM2 columns as CSVs, rather than flowing over into the EXAM3 column. Also this employee did not take EXAM3, so there should be blanks in the EXAM3 columns for that employee.

I apologize for the length and complexity of this question. I would be happy if I could at least figure out a way to break my LISTAGG string into columns that align correctly with the exam code headings.

Thanks in advance,
Russ

Comment: Instead of `listagg` and then "`unlistagg`" you should probably just use a [pivot](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html). I mean... the `listagg` is creative, but it obviously has a lot of caveats as you lose the relationship from the original record in the aggregation, which is exactly what you are trying to preserve for your "`unlistagg`"

Comment: Is this an exam / test for SO patrons ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it sounds like your starting data is one exam per row, yes? Try using [`PIVOT`](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/how-to-convert-rows-to-columns-and-back-again-with-sql-aka-pivot-and-unpivot). That takes multiple rows and creates a single row with multiple columns. So you'd have something like this, after you've already used LISTAGG to put the multiple scores from the same exam on one line:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    ... exam query here ...
)
PIVOT ( MAX( score ), MAX( date ) FOR exam IN ( 1 AS "EXAM1", 2 AS "EXAM2" ... ))
```

The MAX won't do anything, as long as you have one row per employee, per exam, it's just that PIVOT requires an aggregate function.